# Compare two array and get the difference

Tags: php, arrays

I've two array. `$arr1` is like this:-

```
Array
(
    [Size] => L
    [Color] => Purple
    [Brand] => Lee
    [Fabric] => Cotton
)
```

and another array `$arr2` is like this:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Purple
            [Size] => L
            [Brand] => Lee
            [Fabric] => Cotton
            [Price] => 1000
            [Quantity] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Pink
            [Size] => L
            [Brand] => Lee
            [Fabric] => Cotton
            [Price] => 1100
            [Quantity] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Color] => White
            [Size] => L
            [Brand] => Lee
            [Fabric] => Cotton
            [Price] => 1200
            [Quantity] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Black
            [Size] => L
            [Brand] => Lee
            [Fabric] => Cotton
            [Price] => 900
            [Quantity] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Purple
            [Size] => M
            [Brand] => Lee
            [Fabric] => Cotton
            [Price] => 900
            [Quantity] => 5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Purple
            [Size] => S
            [Brand] => Lee
            [Fabric] => Cotton
            [Price] => 900
            [Quantity] => 5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Pink
            [Size] => M
            [Brand] => Lee
            [Fabric] => Cotton
            [Price] => 900
            [Quantity] => 5
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Pink
            [Size] => S
            [Brand] => Lee
            [Fabric] => Cotton
            [Price] => 900
            [Quantity] => 5
        )
)
```

I want to get the price and quantity of `$arr2` if both array matches. For example in this case `$arr1` is having 4 arguments same as `$arr2's` 0th index values. So the resulted array should return 1000 and 5. I've tried `array_diff` and some other function but it doesn't helped me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `array_diff` — Computes the difference of arrays

Comment: i've tried it but it is giving me all the values of $arr2 i want only matched value

Comment: Then why is your question titled "Compare two array and get the **difference**"?

Comment: Perhaps you could post what you expect to see as the result?

Comment: i want resulted array like this:- 
Array
(
            [Color] => Purple
            [Size] => L
            [Brand] => Lee
            [Fabric] => Cotton
            [Price] => 1000
            [Quantity] => 5
        )

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach($arr2 as $arrayIndex=>$element){
        $match = true;
        foreach($arr1 as $key=>$elementToMatch){
                if($element[$key] != $elementToMatch ){
                    $match = false;
                }
                if($match == false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        if($match) {
            return $arr2[$arrayIndex];
        }
    }
```

I would suggest something like this. It's a bit ugly becouse there is loop in a loop, but it would be easiest way to achive this.

Comment: You could also append all matches to an array rather than just returning the first.

Answer (score 0):

Your 
Array 1:-

```
$Arr1=array(array
    (
        "Color" => "Pink",
        "Size" => "L",
        "Brand" => "Lee",
        "Fabric" => "Cotton",
        "Price" => "1100",
        "Quantity" => "5"
    ),array(
        "Color" => "White",
        "Size" => "L",
        "Brand" => "Lee",
        "Fabric" => "Cotton",
        "Price" => "1200",
        "Quantity" => "5"
    ),
    array(
        "Color" => "Black",
        "Size" => "L",
        "Brand" => "Lee",
        "Fabric" => "Cotton",
        "Price" => "1300",
        "Quantity" => "5"
    ),
     array(
        "Color" => "RED",
        "Size" => "L",
        "Brand" => "Lee",
        "Fabric" => "Cotton",
        "Price" => "1100",
        "Quantity" => "5"
    )

    );
```

Array 2:-

```
$Arr2=array
(
    "Size" => "L",
    "Color" => "Purple",
    "Brand" => "Lee",
    "Fabric" => "Cotton"
);




for($x=0;$x<sizeof($Arr1);$x++){
        for($j=$x+1;$j<sizeof($Arr1);$j++){
            if($Arr1[$x]["Price"]==$Arr1[$j]["Price"] && $Arr1[$x]["Quantity"]==$Arr1[$j]["Quantity"]){
            $Arr2["Price"]=$Arr1[$j]["Price"];
            $Arr2["Quantity"]=$Arr1[$j]["Quantity"];
        } 
        }

}

    var_dump($Arr2);
```

Your Output will be

```
'Size' => string 'L' (length=1)
  'Color' => string 'Purple' (length=6)
  'Brand' => string 'Lee' (length=3)
  'Fabric' => string 'Cotton' (length=6)
  'Price' => string '1100' (length=4)
  'Quantity' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the price and quantity is always the last, a simple approach would be this

```
foreach($arr2 as $arr) {
    if(count(array_diff(array_slice($arr,0,4),$arr1))==0) {
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ClemenSwichmann if one of the answers worked for you, you should mark them as an answer so other people would know which answer works for you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$arr1` is one dimensional and `$arr2` is 2 dimensional, you can use following where result contains array of `price` and `quantity` for matched arrays.`

```
 function match_array($arr1, $arr2, $result){
  foreach($arr2 as $k=>$v){
    // calculate diff between array1 and array2[key]
    // if size of diff is 0 array matches
    if(sizeof(array_diff($arr1, $v)) == 0){
        // calculate the diff of array2[key] and array1
        // this will give us the price and quantity
        // push the diff into the result array
        array_push($result, array_diff($v, $arr1));
    }
  }
  print_r($result);
}
$result = array();
$result = match_array($array1, $array2, $result);
print_r($result);
```